# vb.net xml to datagrid

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, import

I try to import a xml file to dataset and show it in a datagridview. I did the step by step tutorial here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekw4dh3f.aspx

This works perfect. My code for this was the following

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
Public filepath As String

     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
        Dim filepath As String
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            filepath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        AuthorsDataSet.ReadXml(filepath)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = AuthorsDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "authors"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The file from the tutorial had the following structure.

```
<Authors_Table>  
  <authors>  
    <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>  
    <au_lname>White</au_lname>  
    <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>  
    <phone>408 496-7223</phone>  
    <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>  
    <city>Menlo Park</city>  
    <state>CA</state>  
    <zip>94025</zip>  
    <contract>true</contract>  
  </authors>  
  <authors>  
    <au_id>213-46-8915</au_id>  
    <au_lname>Green</au_lname>  
    <au_fname>Margie</au_fname>  
    <phone>415 986-7020</phone>  
    <address>309 63rd St. #411</address>  
    <city>Oakland</city>  
    <state>CA</state>  
    <zip>94618</zip>  
    <contract>true</contract>  
  </authors>
</Authors_Table>
```

My problem is my file has a driffrent structure. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SearchResults>
    <TableHeader>
        <ColumnName>Menge</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Einheit</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>ARTIKELNUMMER</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>BEZEICHNUNG 1</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>TEILEART</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Lebenszyklusstatus</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Version</ColumnName>
        <ColumnName>Name</ColumnName>
    </TableHeader>
    <Object>
         <Attribute/>
         <Attribute/>
         <Attribute>14.08.010</Attribute>
         <Attribute>KASSETTE</Attribute>
         <Attribute>BGM</Attribute>
         <Attribute>Wird bearbeitet</Attribute>
         <Attribute>-.2 (Design)</Attribute>
         <Attribute>14_08_010</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object>
        <Attribute> 1</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Stück</Attribute>
        <Attribute>14.08.159</Attribute>
        <Attribute>GEHAEUSE</Attribute>
        <Attribute>ET</Attribute>
        <Attribute>Wird bearbeitet</Attribute>
        <Attribute>-.2 (Design)</Attribute>
        <Attribute>14_08_159</Attribute>
   </Object>
</SearchResults>
```

Is my xml file wrong formatted or is this just a diffrent kind of format? I tried to import it with the following code but nothing happens. There was no error of info.

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
Public filepath As String

     Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
        Dim filepath As String
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            filepath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        AuthorsDataSet.ReadXml(filepath)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = AuthorsDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "object"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but the two example XML files are obviously different. I am not sure what format the second one is, however, if you want to use the `ReadXml` method as the first example demonstrates, then you are most likely going to have to convert the second file to the xml format. I would think it would not be that difficult to convert.

Comment: The tag object in xml has a capital 'O' while your code has lower case 'o'.